# Gmail openinviter fails

Tags: php, openid, gmail

I have been using openinviter for my website and when i try to fetch contacts from my gmail, which has almost 1000 contacts, i get an error saying the username and password is incorrect... 
but it works fine with my friend's gmail, which has less than 100 contacts... what could be the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually a timeout issue.  Whenever the plug-in fails, the default functionality just gives the one error message about incorrect username/password.  It probably should be enhanced to show other possible errors or at the very least, a generic 'error occurred'.  In that way, it wouldn't be so misleading.

In many of the plug-ins, you will see the timeout overridden.  look at the yahoo plugin for example.  it has:

```
protected $timeout=30;
```

the base plugin will 5 by default.  Unless you have great bandwidth, this probably won't be long enough for a large amount of contacts.  Increase to 30 or something of your choosing.

Answer (score -3):

The issue could be incorrect username and password. *scnr*

Comment: But iam giving the correct username and password for my gmail login. I first thought that it is the case with the php setting: max_execution_time. I had it as 60 seconds. But even if i try to increase it, no use.

Comment: If an error message complains about auth credentials it's generally because – guess what – wrong auth credentials. Try other operations like connect and disconnect or send an email. If the error message is the same you should be convinced that it's not related to the number of contacts.

Comment: I have similar issues, sometimes it randomly fails